# Struts2 - Cross domain redirect using POST method

Tags: struts2

struts 2.0.11 - Currently I'm in my local machine and have two different web applications running under tomcat (struts 2.0.11) and weblogic respectively.

**Tomcat:**

Link: localhost:8080/retail/order.action

struts.xml:

```
<action name="order" method="execute" class="com.retail.action.OrderAction">
  <result name="redirect" type="redirect">
    <param name="location">${weblogicURL}?user=${user}</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

I have necessary attributes like 'weblogicURL' and 'user' in OrderAction in Tomcat Web app. Now this is working and weblogic resource is getting accessed as GET method like the following,

```
localhost:7020/retail/orderPortal?user=test
```

I would like to access weblogic using POST method from tomcat, is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: is there a specific reason that you are using such an old version of S2?

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi This is an existing application that was developed sometime back, i'm just making some changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the [redirect](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/redirect-result.html) documentation says

> session or with web parameters (url?name=value) which can be OGNL expressions.

Which indicates that we can only send data only by get method and what you are trying to do is not possible as of now.

One possible solution seems to use Action Chaining.Please go through the official document for details

- [Action-Chaining](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/action-chaining.html)

Comment: Tried Action chaining, but couldn't chain to an action running in a different application server. I will go ahead with redirect. But will go for encryption of parameter values in the url. I didn't get any other answers and your answer also look like correct, so I make your answer as accepeted.

Comment: @SyAu:Application running with different containers can be problematic in Action-chaining, though this approach is never preferred one and agree with you to go ahead with `redirect` result